# Hyperlinks in pdf of glossary entries do not point to glossary/acronyms list page

Tags: glossaries

I'm writing a thesis report using the Laval university [ulthese](https://ctan.org/pkg/ulthese?lang=en) template and added a glossary for acronyms as described in this [overleaf guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries).

I am then inserting acronyms into the main report content using `\gls` or `\acrshort` commands.

Everything is working fine from a presentation perspective but the hyperlinks in the final pdf added to each use of an acronym do not redirect the acronyms page.  They link to the title page instead.

I simply added `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`, `\makeglossaries`, and `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` to the template as follows:

```
\documentclass[MSc,english,french]{ulthese}

...
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% Acronyms
\newacronym{SAG}{SAG}{semi-autogenous grinding mill}
... etc.

\begin{document}

\frontmatter                    % pages liminaires

\frontispice                    % production de la page frontispice

\include{resume}                % résumé français
\include{abstract}              % résumé anglais
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents                % production de la TdM
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables                   % production de la liste des tableaux
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures                  % production de la liste des figures
\cleardoublepage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\include{remerciements}         % remerciements

\mainmatter                     % corps du document

\include{introduction}          % introduction
\include{chapitre1}             % chapitre 1
\include{chapitre2}             % chapitre 2
\include{chapitre3}             % chapitre 3
\include{conclusion}            % conclusion

\appendix                       % annexes le cas échéant

\include{annexe}                % annexe A

\bibliography{references}                 % production de la bibliographie

\end{document}
```

Is there something else I should be adding before/after the `\printglossary` command?

**Update**

I fixed the problem of the list of acronyms not showing in the table of contents so that is not a related issue.  Code above amended accordingly.

Comment: Going to Doc-Start is the default when it can't find the target.  At least it means that hyperref was loaded, even though I don't see it in the MWE.  You could try looking at the aux file for the link names, although they don't always show up there.  Two likely causes are loading packages out of order, and duplicate values for \thepage.

Comment: Thanks. There is no reference to hyperref in the tex documents although it is mentioned a few times in the ulthese cls file, e.g.: `\newif\ifUL@hyperref     \UL@hyperreftrue` and `\DeclareOption{nohyperref}{\UL@hyperreffalse}`. Also: `\AtEndPreamble{\RequirePackage{hyperref}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution based on the comment by John Kormylo.  I just added the hyperref package before the glossaries setup commands in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

Now the links go to the correct line in the glossary list.

Thanks.